# Reflection: Get All properties that implements an interface in a parameter Object

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class which has many objects of other classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public USD USD { get; set; }
    public CAD CAD { get; set; }
    public EUR EUR { get; set; }
    public AED AED { get; set; }
    public AFN AFN { get; set; }
    public ALL ALL { get; set; }
}
```

Each of these classes implements an interface called `ICurrency`; the `ICurrency` Interface has a string property called "symbol" like that:

```
public class EUR : ICurrency 
{/*code logic*/}
```

Finally I have a method Which takes the `RootObject` instance as a parameter;

```
public object Add22(Rootobject rootobject)
{}
```

I need to get all the values of the "symbol" property of all the instances passed in the `rootobject` variable.

I think this can easily be done through reflection by creating a list of `ICurrency` and adding all the objects in it then looping through it.

Am I right? and if yes; then how to make it? or there is a better approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Type.GetProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get a type's properties and [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) to find whether a property can be assigned to an `ICurrency` variable. You can retrieve all matching properties with a LINQ query :

```
var currencyProps=typeof(Rootobject).GetProperties()                                   
                   .Where(pi=>typeof(ICurrency).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
                   .ToArray();
```

or

```
var currencyProps=( from pi in typeof(Rootobject).GetProperties()                                   
                    where typeof(ICurrency).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType)
                  ).ToArray();
```

You can cache the `currencyProps` array in a static field and reuse it with any object :

```
static PropertyInfo[] _currencyProps;

static void InitializeCurrencyProps()
{
    var currencyProps=( from pi in typeof(RootObject).GetProperties()                                   
                        where typeof(ICurrency).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType)
                        select pi);
    _currencyProps=currencyProps.ToArray();
}
```

Once you have all the PropertyInfo object you want, you can use [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) to read a property value from a specific instance, eg :

```
_currencyProps[0].GetValue(rootObject);
```

To find all properties with values, ie not noll, you can use another query :

```
var values=_currencyProps.Select(pi=>new {pi.Name,Value=pi.GetValue(rootobject)})
                        .Where(val=>val.Value!=null)
                        .ToArray();
```

or

```
var values = ( from pi in _currencyProps
               let value=pi.GetValue(rootobject)
               where value !=null
               select new {pi.Name,value}
             ).ToArray();
```

You can create a dictionary instead of an array with `ToDictionary()` :

```
var values = ( from pi in _currencyProps
               let value=pi.GetValue(rootobject)
               where value !=null
               select new {pi.Name,Value=value}
             ).ToDictionary(pair=>pair.Name,pair=>pair.Value);

var usd=values["USD"];
```

Comment: Many Thanks; I have used this part after getting the Values array to dig into the needed properties:
foreach (var x in values)
            {
                ICurrency iCurrency = (ICurrency)x.value;
                //Rest of code
            }